# Get text value of selected option in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have some custom Jquery which grabs the id's from a select list, and populates a secondary select list with those that are selected.

I have this working well, however I need the secondary select list needs to display the text value of the selected option.  Currently I just get the actual id.

Can anybody assist please?

JQUERY

```
$('#myselect').change(function() {
        var row = $(".chosen-select").val();
        $('#secondSelect').html('');
        jQuery.each(row, function(i, val) {
            $('#secondSelect').append('<option value=' + val + '>' + val) + '</option>';
        });
});
```

HTML

First select list

```
<select data-placeholder="Choose cars..." class="chosen-select" name="myselect[]" id="myselect" multiple>   
<option value="1">Vauxhall</option>                                                                                          
<option value="2">Volvo</option>
etc...
</select>
```

Second select list

```
<select name="secondSelect" id="secondSelect">
    <option value="">Select Model</option>
    should be populated here..
</select>
```

Comment: I don't really understand what's going on but you can use `.text()` rather than `.val()`.

Comment: OK, I'm quite possibly missing something that is straight forward to you.  I appreciate that I can use text() but how I implement it is where I fall over.

Comment: `$('#secondSelect').html( $('<option />', {value : $(".chosen-select").val(), text : $(".chosen-select").text()}) );`

Comment: check this fiddle, is this what you wanted? http://jsfiddle.net/Lkyvbdsz/

Comment: Hi eg_dac, almost :-) It wasn't populating the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0w1nvhqb/1/)

```
$('#myselect').change(function() {
        $('#secondSelect').html('');
        jQuery.each($("option:selected",this), function(i, val) {
            $('#secondSelect').append($(val).clone());
        });
});
```